# Turning off Require Password on a filevault enabled MacBook Air 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, security, password, filevault

I am trying to use the product form soma-zone.com called RedHand.  The only catch is you must have Require Password turned off in the Security Preferences Pane.  RedHand won't start until it is turned off, but I have filevault 2 enabled which automatically sets Require Password to true and immediatley.  I can trick it for a few seconds using

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword 0
```

This only works for a few seconds then the default is changed back automatically to 1.  Is there a cache file or another work around to disable Require Password when FileVault 2 is enabled?

Link to product [RedHand](http://www.soma-zone.com/RedHand/)

MacBook Air 2011 running 10.9.5

Answer (score 1):

There is another piece of software similar to RedHand called [Watchmac (from bloo7)](http://bloo7.com/watchmac/). I suggest you try using Watchmac as a work-around to this issue.

Comment: what version are you running it on.  Doesn't open for me on 10.9.5

Comment: After running it now, I'm unable to use Watchmac either. Sorry about the useless answer.